# This Python script returns "KeyError: '6'" and I don't know why

Tags: python

This script is the answer to an assignment I have. The problem arises below the section I have commented as "Task 3".
My code works perfectly fine, or at least seems to do so, as it prints out the correct nodes in the graph. However, for some reason, I get "KeyError: '6'", and I don't understand why.

Here's my entire script:

```
# Task 1
# The answer is D, All of the above

# Task 2
def binary_tree(r):
    return [r, [], []]

def get_left_child(root):
    return root[1]

def get_right_child(root):
    return root[2]

def insert_left_child(root, new_branch):
    t = root.pop(1)
    if len(t) > 1:
        root.insert(1, [new_branch, t, []])
    else:
        root.insert(1, [new_branch, [], []])
    return root

def insert_right_child(root, new_branch):
    t = root.pop(2)
    if len(t) > 1:
        root.insert(2, [new_branch, [], t])
    else:
        root.insert(2, [new_branch, [], []])
    return root

my_tree = binary_tree('a')

insert_left_child(my_tree, 'b')
insert_right_child(my_tree, 'c')

insert_right_child(get_right_child(my_tree), 'd')
insert_left_child(get_right_child(get_right_child(my_tree)), 'e')

print(my_tree, "\nThe answer is C")

# Task 3
class Graph:
    graph = dict()

    def add_edge(self, node, neighbour):
        if node not in self.graph:
            self.graph[node] = [neighbour]
        else:
            self.graph[node].append(neighbour)

    def print_graph(self):
        print(self.graph)

    def breadth_first_search(self, node):
        searched = []
        search_queue = [node]

        while search_queue:
            searched.append(node)
            node = search_queue.pop(0)
            print("[", node, end=" ], ")

            for neighbour in self.graph[node]:
                if neighbour not in searched:
                    searched.append(neighbour)
                    search_queue.append(neighbour)


def build_my_graph2():
    my_graph = Graph()
    my_graph.add_edge("1", "2")
    my_graph.add_edge("2", "3")
    my_graph.add_edge("3", "5")
    my_graph.add_edge("4", "5")
    my_graph.add_edge("5", "6")
    my_graph.breadth_first_search("1")

build_my_graph2()
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: @garosath Could you also consider a Reproducible Example... Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You get a KeyError when you call for a key that is not in the dictionary. Based on your add_edge function, it looks like you create a key for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but you add a value only for 6.

Here you are requesting a value for key 6, but 6 in itself is not a key.

```
for neighbour in self.graph[node]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = mydict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.

Feel free to read more about KeyError exceptions in Python here: https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/

Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: It tells me line 77, 75 and 62. But thing is, the value that is displayed as the KeyError is shown to be the 2nd parameter of the .add_edge. As the code is posted, it says "KeyError: '6", but if I comment out my_graph.add_edge("5", "6"), the KeyError becomes 5, which corresponds to the 2nd parameter of the .add_edge before it, and it continues.

Comment: That is because if you remove my_graph.add_edge("5", "6"), you never create a dictionary pair with {5: [6]}. Hence when you navigate through the graph, you do not find a key 5